# How to use ZeroMQ for raw UDP?

Tags: udp, zeromq

I have a client, whose code I can't change -- but I'd like to (re)write using **`ZeroMQ`** sockets.

The clients use both raw **`TCP`** and raw **`UDP`** sockets.

I know I can use `ZMQ_ROUTER_RAW` for raw `TCP` sockets, but **what about for raw `UDP` datastreams?**

Comment: zmq has no UDP support.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks.

Comment: Does that mean you can only use pgm/epgm ? There's no way to set up a socket with upd://XXX:123 like you would with TCP ?

Comment: http://api.zeromq.org/master:zmq-udp

Comment: may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45153535/1052261

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UDP Support for ZMQ is now documented here:
http://api.zeromq.org/master:zmq-udp

Pyzmq version 18 has it as well, stating: "Protocols supported include tcp, udp, pgm, epgm, inproc and ipc."  That said, my experimentation with Python hasn't found a solution that works yet.  I get "protocol is not compatible with socket type" errors.

Answer (score 11):

Support for UDP in ZeroMQ is brand new.  The documentation for the new socket types (Radio/Dish) was just pushed to the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/commit/fee84134e7c1f30578bb8b013e911b7dbde79ea6) a few days ago.  As of right now, though, it still looks like there's no raw UDP support, but perhaps it will stem out of this new functionality.

I'd recommend commenting on the existing thread about adding UDP support:  https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/issues/807 .

Comment: Glad you have mentioned this, Hank. Besides somdoron's ( he is active on S/O too ) work on `UDP` in `RADIO/DISH` there is a general notice in **ZeroMQ Feature List: "Since version 4.2, `libzmq` supports `UDP` in Unicast and Multicast modes."**

Comment: 3 years on this answer is no longer relevant.

Comment: Clicking through to the github issue #807 link, comment from April 2016: "Since version 4.2, libzmq also has UDP support in unicast and multicast modes."