# What do I need to do to get ZMQ_RADIO / ZMQ_DISH to work properly?

Tags: c++, linux, zeromq

I'm attempting to use the ZMQ draft specs `ZMQ_RADIO` and `ZMQ_DISH`.  I built libzmq and cppzmq with CMake `ExternalProject` and and the flag `ENABLE_DRAFTS=ON` and verified it was built with drafts using the `zmq_has()` function.  I modified the standard [hello world example](http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:hwserver) to use radio and dish and cannot get them to talk.  I also get compilation errors that `ZMQ_RADIO` and `ZMQ_DISH` are undefined.  I defined them manually and it compiles but I never get an actual connection so it seems like something else is wrong.

Here's my code:

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)
project(zmq_udp)

include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(libzmq
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq
    GIT_TAG master
    CMAKE_ARGS 
      -DENABLE_DRAFTS=ON
      -DWITH_PERF_TOOL=OFF 
      -DZMQ_BUILD_TESTS=OFF 
      -DENABLE_CPACK=OFF
      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/zmq
      -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/zmq/lib
      -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}
      -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}
      -DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS=${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS}
)

ExternalProject_Add(cppzmq
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq
    GIT_TAG master
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy <SOURCE_DIR>/zmq.hpp ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/zmq/include/zmq.hpp
    TEST_COMMAND ""
)

add_dependencies(cppzmq libzmq)

set(ZEROMQ_LIBNAME "libzmq.so")
set(ZEROMQ_INCLUDE_DIRS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/zmq/include)
set(ZEROMQ_LIBRARIES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/zmq/lib/${ZEROMQ_LIBNAME})

include_directories(${ZEROMQ_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(server server.cpp)
add_executable(client client.cpp)
add_dependencies(server cppzmq)
add_dependencies(client cppzmq)
target_link_libraries(server ${ZEROMQ_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(client ${ZEROMQ_LIBRARIES})
```

server.cpp

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#define ZMQ_DISH 15

int main ()
{
    std::cout << zmq_has("draft") << std::endl;

    zmq::context_t context (1);
    zmq::socket_t socket (context, ZMQ_DISH);
    socket.bind ("udp://127.0.0.1:5555");

    while (true)
    {
        zmq::message_t request;

        socket.recv (&request);
        std::cout << "Received Hello" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

client.cpp

```
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

#define ZMQ_RADIO 14

int main ()
{
    zmq::context_t context (1);
    zmq::socket_t socket (context, ZMQ_RADIO);

    std::cout << "Connecting to hello world server…" << std::endl;
    socket.connect ("udp://127.0.0.1:5555");

    for (int request_nbr = 0; request_nbr != 10; request_nbr++)
    {
        zmq::message_t request (5);
        memcpy (request.data (), "Hello", 5);
        std::cout << "Sending Hello " << request_nbr << "…" << std::endl;
        socket.send (request);

        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The server outputs a 1 as expected for the `zmq_has()` function, which should verify libzmq was built with the draft API mode on.

### What do I need to do to get `RADIO/DISH` to work properly?

I'd like to use ZMQ on a project as a UDP receiver to receive some UDP packets from a non-ZMQ application.

Comment: _" I defined them manually ..."_ Are you sure that is a good idea?

Comment: I defined the socket types manually just in an effort to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RADIO and DISH are in draft state and not available in stable build. If you need to access DRAFT API, build zmq from this [link](https://build.opensuse.org/project/show/network:messaging:zeromq:git-draft)

The following is part of **zmq.hpp**

```
// These functions are DRAFT and disabled in stable releases, and subject to 
// change at ANY time until declared stable.                                 
    #ifdef ZMQ_BUILD_DRAFT_API

    //DRAFT Socket types.                                                       
#define ZMQ_SERVER 12
#define ZMQ_CLIENT 13
#define ZMQ_RADIO 14
#define ZMQ_DISH 15
#define ZMQ_GATHER 16
#define ZMQ_SCATTER 17
#define ZMQ_DGRAM 18
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is example of working with those two. I already tested it.

Most important thing you need to check that you don't load your system zmq library.
In my case I did such thing in cmake:

```
set(ENABLE_DRAFTS ON)

add_subdirectory(libzmq)
set_target_properties(libzmq PROPERTIES PREFIX "dev-")

# If you want target
add_library(CppZeroMQ INTERFACE)

target_link_libraries(CppZeroMQ INTERFACE $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:libzmq>$<$<CONFIG:Release>:libzmq-static>)
# For CPP headers (you may install and change path here)
target_include_directories(CppZeroMQ INTERFACE my/path/to/cppzmq)
target_compile_definitions(CppZeroMQ INTERFACE ZMQ_BUILD_DRAFT_API=1)
```

Thanks to that it will distinguish between system lib and yours from source. Probably system library isn't using DRAFTS.

---

Server/Publisher part

```
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t publisher(context, ZMQ_RADIO);
    // We need set IP of destination, sad but true
    publisher.connect("udp://127.0.0.1:30666");

    std::string text;
    text.reserve(128);

    int number = 0;
    while(publisher.connected())
    {
        std::chrono::microseconds timestamp = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(
            std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());

        text.clear();
        text += std::to_string(timestamp.count());
        text += ";";
        text += std::to_string(++number);

        zmq::message_t update{text.data(), text.size()};
        update.set_group("test");
        std::cout << "Sending: " << timestamp << " number:" << number << std::endl;
        publisher.send(update);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    }
```

---

Client/Subscriber part

```
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t subscriber(context, ZMQ_DISH);
    subscriber.bind("udp://*:30666");
    subscriber.join("test");

    int previousNumber = 0;
    int lostCount = -1;

    while(subscriber.connected())
    {
        zmq::message_t update;

        subscriber.recv(&update);

        std::string_view text(update.data<const char>(), update.size());
        std::cout << text;

        auto splitPoint = text.find(';');
        std::string serverTime = std::string{text.substr(0, splitPoint)};
        std::string serverNumber = std::string{text.substr(splitPoint + 1)};
        auto number = std::stoi(serverNumber);
        if(number != previousNumber + 1)
        {
            ++lostCount;
        }
        previousNumber = number;

        const auto diff =
            system_clock::now() -
            system_clock::time_point{std::chrono::microseconds{std::stoull(serverTime)}};

        // Beautify at: https://github.com/gelldur/common-cpp/blob/master/src/acme/beautify.h
        std::cout << " ping:" << Beautify::nice{diff} << "UDP lost: " << lostCount << std::endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Houston, we have a problem:

I am not familiar with conditional builds and including draft-API(s) in recent ZeroMQ versions. If it were indeed intended to work your assumed way, the **`#define`**-s ought have been already solved there, haven't they?

Maybe you have digged from some GitHub source the correct `#define` ordinals for `ZMQ_RADIO` + `ZMQ_DISH`, compatible with core-functions, but a general approach to just manually:

```
#define                        A_NOT_IMPLEMENTED_CABLE_TV_BROADCAST_ARCHETYPE -1234
void   *dsh = zmq_socket( ctx, A_NOT_IMPLEMENTED_CABLE_TV_BROADCAST_ARCHETYPE );
assert( dsh              && "INF: a socket instantiation from [ctx] failed." );

        rc = bind( dsh, "udp://*:5555" );
assert( rc == 0          && "INF: a socket .bind( 'udp://*.5555' ) failed.");
```

sounds a lot suspicious, even with a promise of the flag `ENABLE_DRAFTS=ON`, doesn't it?

---

### Summary

If your project aims at using `RADIO/DISH`, carefully review both the published API ( warnings about not-implemented / not-released features ), where you find also other mandatory steps:

> Radio-dish is using groups (vs Pub-sub topics), Dish sockets can join a group and each message sent by Radio sockets belong to a group.
>   Groups are null terminated strings limited to 16 chars length (including null). The intention is to increase the length to 40 chars (including null).
>   Groups are matched using exact matching (vs prefix matching of PubSub).

**`ZMQ_RADIO`** side must use **`zmq_msg_set_group(3)`** to first assign a message to a group.

**`ZMQ_DISH`** side must use a call to  **`zmq_join(3)`** so as to "enter" a group so as to receive any message, as by default there is, obviously, no membership upon it's instantiation.

**`ZMQ_DISH`** side may use a call to **`zmq_msg_group(3)`** to get the group the message actually belongs to.

---

### ZeroMQ is in W.I.P. - so may like to check [nanomsg](/questions/tagged/nanomsg) for similar services.

If in a need and hurry, Martin Sustrik has initiated another smart messaging/signalling tool - the [nanomsg](/questions/tagged/nanomsg).

After some troubles, the  [nanomsg](/questions/tagged/nanomsg) seems to have rolled out production release, where Scalable Formal Communication Patterns may help you in your Project goals. **Worth a try.**

Comment: The main goal is just a simple UDP receiver without using cumbersome libraries or re-inventing socket communication.  The project already uses ZeroMQ for other reasons so it seemed nice to possibly re-use it for the needed UDP receive duty.  I understand it's a work in progress and am ok with that, it's just not well documented (which is understandable and also why I asked the question here).  I'm considering [LCM](https://lcm-proj.github.io/index.html) as an alternative but will check out nanomsg too.  Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help robots get out there into outer space :o)   Have you tried first to setup properly the calls to **`zmq_msg_set_group()`** on the `ZMQ_RADIO`-side + the **`zmq_join()`** on the `ZMQ_DISH`-side to work as defined?

Comment: So, I'm reviewing the [documentation I've found](http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-udp) and it's obviously different from the documentation you're looking at.  Would you mind linking to where you found this documentation (or did you just glean it from the code?).

Comment: If you are familiar with `PUB`/`SUB` topic-filter subscriptions, the new `RADIO/DISH` is just trying to avoid `.setsockopt( zmq.SUBSCRIBE, <aTopicFilterLeftMatchingFRAGMENT> )` and exposes another API mechanism, via a socket-related call to `zmq_join()`, adding some further limitations ( exact match, NULL-termination, zero support for multi-part messages ). But it shall work for you.